# Does my husband need to get the "registration certificate as a qualified person" for me to apply for a EEA family permit?

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa, eu-spouses

My husband and I were studying for a Master's in London. Now my husband got a job in London. I have a Uruguayan passport. My husband has both Uruguayan and Italian passports. I am going to my home country to apply for an EEA Family Permit.

*My concern is whether my husband needs to first apply for a "Registration Certificate as a Qualified Person" (we have been in the UK for more than 3 months) in order for me to be able to apply for my EEA Family Permit in Uruguay, or if this is not mandatory.*

Comment: I believe it is not mandatory for the EEA family permit, but it can only help.  But you write "we have been in the UK for more than three months"; if you're in the UK, why go back to Uruguay to apply for the family permit?  You can apply directly for a residence card in the UK.

Comment: Furthermore, under the UK's implementation of the freedom of movement directive, the EEA FP doesn't bring much benefit beyond allowing you toenter the UK more easily.  In particular, it is not necessary to hold an EEA FP in order for you to remain in the UK.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. One doubt, if I were to apply for a residence card, being the spouse of an EEA National would i have to prove dependency to him? I read that this is the "stage 4" check that the home office does... not sure if it applies for me as the wife. I am dependent on my husband economically but only since this last month because before we were funded by a scholarship. If I need to prove dependency, would 1 pay slip be enough, should I wait for some more months to apply or should I provide my bank statement showing he passes cash to me?

Comment: Spouses do not need to show dependency.  If you can ask a separate question I will provide a reference.

Comment: For anyone following along in the comments, that question is [Residence Card, proving dependency and health insurance](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/12546/2440).

Answer (score 2):

In the [documents you must provide](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/documents-you-must-provide) page, the only requirements are:

> You must show that your EEA family member has a permanent right of residence or is one of the following if they’ve been in the UK for more than 3 months:
>
> - working, for example an employment contract, wage slips or a letter from an employer
> - self-employed (for example contracts, invoices or audited accounts with bank statements) and paying tax and National Insurance
> - studying, for example a letter from the school, college or university
> - financially independent, for example bank statements
>
> Your family member must have full health insurance (comprehensive sickness insurance) if they’re studying or financially independent.
>
> The [guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/application-for-eea-family-permit-form-vaf5) has more examples of documents you can show.

The registration certificate is not listed, so it is not necessary, although it might help.  The guide to supporting documents ([PDF](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/261446/eea-family-permit.pdf)) also does not list the registration certificate.

However, your question implies that you are already in the UK.  If that is true, you only need an EEA family permit if you want to leave the UK and re-enter.  To remain in the UK, you should apply directly for a [residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card).