# Residence Card, proving dependency and health insurance

Tags: uk-visa, health-insurance, residence-cards

My husband and I have been in the UK for more than a year studying a masters. My husband just got a job and has Italian passport (I am a non-EU), therefore i was thinking of applying for a residence card as EU spouse of a qualified person. I see that one of the things they ask is to prove **dependency**. How can I prove this? I was thinking of showing my husband's wage slip, is this enough or should I also show that he transfers cash to me? He hasn't done this yet since till last month we were financed by a scholarship... 
Additionally, about the **"Comprehensive Sickness Insurance"**, my husband gets this by his employer but after the first 3 months of employment, therefore should he get a Health Insurance in the meantime or is it ok with what is stated in the contract? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary for a non-EEA spouse to prove that dependency on the EEA spouse.  See for example the guidance document [Free Movement Rights: direct family members of European Economic Area (EEA) nationals](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/610197/direct_family_members_of_eea_nationals_v5_0.pdf) (PDF), page 10:

> **A child aged 21 or over and any relatives in the ascending family line** must prove they are dependent on the EEA national sponsor or their spouse or civil partner.

(emphasis added)

Note that there are two categories of relatives who must prove dependency; spouses are not among them.

Comprehensive sickness insurance is required only of students and those of independent means.  See for example the guidance document [EEA(FM): guidance notes](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/506062/EEA_FM__guide-to-supporting-documents_v1_3_2015-12-04_KP.pdf) (PDF), page 9:

> Comprehensive sickness insurance (**students and self-sufficient persons**) 
>
> Evidence of your sponsor’s comprehensive sickness insurance **for any period in which they were a student or self-sufficient person,** such as their European Health Insurance Card (EHIC) (formerly form E111), S1 (formerly E106/E109/E121), S2 (formerly E112), S3, policy document from a private medical insurer – see notes for sections 15 and 16.

(emphasis added)

Since your husband is a worker, he is neither a student nor a self-sufficient person, so there is no need to worry about comprehensive sickness insurance.